# How do I turn these series of commands into a function?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

Hi Im fairly new to R and trying to self teach, I want to turn the following set of code into a for loop/function but Im struggling as to how to accomplish this because there isnt a uniform set of possible entries.

Here is the code as it is in non-function form:

```
    colnames(x)[36] <- "DriveToFoodSource_BIN"
    x[,36][x[,36] == "Drive"] <- "1"
    x[,36][x[,36] == ""] <- "0"

    colnames(x)[37] <- "BusToFoodSource_BIN"
    x[,37][x[,37] == "Ride the bus"] <- "1"
    x[,37][x[,37] == ""] <- "0"

    colnames(x)[38] <- "TaxiToFoodSource_BIN"
    x[,38][x[,38] == "Taxi cab"] <- "1"
    x[,38][x[,38] == ""] <- "0"

    colnames(x)[39] <- "FriendsBringFoodSource_BIN"
    x[,39][x[,39] == "Friend"] <- "1"
    x[,39][x[,39] == ""] <- "0"

    colnames(x)[40] <- "WalkToFoodSource_BIN"
    x[,40][x[,40] == "Walk"] <- "1"
    x[,40][x[,40] == ""] <- "0"

    colnames(x)[41] <- "DeliveryFoodSource_BIN"
    x[,41][x[,41] == "Food is delivered"] <- "1"
    x[,41][x[,41] == ""] <- "0"

    colnames(x)[42] <- "OtherWayToFoodSource_BIN"
    x[,42][x[,42] == "Drive"] <- "1"
    x[,42][x[,42] == ""] <- "0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in two steps

1) Change the columns to binary by comparing the columns with a `vector` of values replicated to make the lengths same, then coerce the `logical` to `binary` and assign those values to the columns of interest

```
x[36:42] <- +(x[36:42]== v1[col(x[36:42])])
```

2) Change the columns names of those columns

```
colnames(x)[36:42] <- v2
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Drive", "Ride the bus", "Taxi cab", "Friend", "Walk", "Food is delivered",
    "Drive")
v2 <- c("DriveToFoodSource_BIN", "BusToFoodSource_BIN", "TaxiToFoodSource_BIN", 
   "FriendsBringFoodSource_BIN", "WalkToFoodSource_BIN","DeliveryFoodSource_BIN",
           "OtherWayToFoodSource_BIN")
```

Comment: Wow thats so helpful! thanks so much, one quick question though. What does the + sign mean in front of the (x[36:42]?

Comment: @EricGorski  The comparison `==` gives you a logical matrix ie. TRUE/FALSE values, which can be coerced to binary `1/0` by using `+`

Comment: @EricGorski it's an ugly hack for something achieved by `as.numeric` in normal R code.